# Prove: $2^{\aleph_0}\not=\aleph_{\epsilon_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Prove: $2^{\aleph_0}\not=\aleph_{\epsilon_0}$
I would like a hint for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** If $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then the cofinality of $\aleph_\delta$ is the same cofinality of $\delta$. Note that $\varepsilon_0$ is countable.

Comment: I haven't studied about the cofinality of aleph numbers. I think I need to use König's theorem, but I don't know how to represent $\aleph_{\epsilon_0}$ as a sum

Comment: @Gyt: Yes, precisely. Note that $\{\aleph_\alpha\mid\alpha<\varepsilon_0\}$ is a countable set. What is the sum of all those cardinals?